# Trying to call PHP function using jQuery.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my `index.php`:

```
<?php
function type_my_text(){
    echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'textfield')
}

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if($action == "typer"){
    type_my_text();
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            function call_typer(){
                $.post('index.php', {action : "typer"});
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="textfield">
            <input type="submit" value="type" onclick="call_typer()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this code, I'm trying to call `type_my_text` PHP function using ajax (`post()`, in the case) when I click the submit button. I mounted this code based on other answers, but It isn't working and I don't know what I'm missing.

The process:

`html button click` -> `call js call_typer() function` -> `make jQuery.post() ajax request` -> `php var $action receive "typer"` -> `call php function type_my_text()`

I'm expecting that this code writes on page what I wrote in the textfield. When I submit the button, nothing happens. I think the ajax request is happening, but `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action')` is receiving nothing or not what I'm expecting (`"typer"` as value).

No error is being raised.

Comment: Firstly, you need to define "it isn't working". What do you observe? What were you expecting? Secondly, I'm pretty sure there are tons of good answers on SO highlighting the difference between client-side and server-side script, which is what this question seems to be about.

Comment: Your PHP code says `login()` instead of `type_my_text()` - where is `type_my_text()` ever called? Secondly, this is an AJAX call - you didn't show the code to process the return data, or did you not even have it?

Comment: Fixed the `login()` thing. And sorry, I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: Are you using PHP 4.1 or inferior?

Comment: Then use `$_POST`. And your function `call_typer()` is only sending 1 value, it is missing your 2nd value. Also, it won't do anything since you don't have the 3rd parameter set to a function, on `$.post()`.

Comment: Also, if you want to write in an already-loaded page, use Javascript to find a suitable element to write on, instead of calling a php file in the server.

Comment: I'm using `filter_input(INPUT_POST, ... )` instead of `$_POST`. I just need to send `"typer"`, what would be the second value? Do I really need the 3rd parm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.post()` is an AJAX request to `index.php`. Whenever you make an AJAX request, or any HTTP request at all, the browser sends out a HTTP request to the server (the one hosting `index.php`), and gets some data back in return. In the special case of HTTP AJAX requests, the browser sends HTTP request asynchronously without refreshing the page, and the response is received behind the scenes from server.

A typical AJAX POST call in jQuery should look like this:

```
$.post("index.php", {action: 'typer'}, function( data ) {
    // do something with data, e.g.
    console.log(data);
});
```

Your server file (`index.php`) should then return some data to the AJAX request. Because you have used `index.php` to serve AJAX data as well as normal HTML, it should look something like this:

```
<?php
function type_my_text() { ... }

// Either serve data to AJAX call, or serve HTML of index page.
if ($_POST['action'] == "typer"){
    // serve AJAX call
    type_my_text();
}
else {
    // serve HTML
?>

<html>
 ...
</html>
<?php
}
```

But this is messy.

It would be preferable to apply some separation of concerns - use HTML files purely for serving HTML, and PHP purely for serving AJAX content. In other words, take your HTML and put it into `index.html`, then create `ajax.php` (or whatever name you want), and put your PHP code in it. You then wouldn't need to do ugly things like the above - mixing HTML code inside your PHP file. And of course, remember to change the URL in your JS.

**Additional:**

In your JS making the AJAX request, make sure you **prevent the default browser action** of submitting the form - which is a fresh page request. Otherwise, you aren't doing AJAX at all.

The cleanest way to do this in jQuery:

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // important - to prevent page refresh
    $.post(...);        // the AJAX call here
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="textfield">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Main things to note:

1. Give your form an ID so you can find it in jQuery efficiently. No action/anything else required.
2. I presume you'd do something with your `textfield` input after AJAX.
3. Avoid using inline JS.

Comment: This should be marked as accepted before the whole solution implemented fully. It contains main idea behind and said in a good manner. plus one.

Comment: That's really nice, but that's not so different of what I'm doing, except by 3rd arg at `post()` function. I think in this case, this won't make difference. When I `print_r($_POST);` using your example, I don't have a `[action] => 'typer'` as expected.

Comment: Where did you put your `print_r`? Frankly, I'm surprised that you don't think you are doing anything different from what I have written - one, you're ignoring your AJAX return; two, even if you do, your AJAX returns a whole unnecessary chunk of HTML; three, you're mixing HTML + PHP.

Comment: I gave you a +1.But I put `print_r` before the `if`. I tested your example with the 3rd arg too.

Comment: Passing the form serialized wouldn't help. Sounds like the POST variables are somehow not received on the server-side.

Comment: I suspect you weren't even looking at the params passed by the AJAX call at all. I have added some more tips in the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: I solved here passing the serialized form. But I really appreciate your help!